# C++ int64 * double == off by one

Tags: c++

Below is the code I've tested in a 64-bit environment and 32-bit.  The result is off by one precisely each time.  The expected result is: 1180000000 with the actual result being 1179999999.  I'm not sure exactly why and I was hoping someone could educate me:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double odds = 1.18;
  int64_t st = 1000000000;
  int64_t res = st * odds;
  cout << "result: " << res << endl;
  return 1;
}
```

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You are going to get this sort of problem with floating point.  `double` is double-precision, not infinite-precision!  Try `cout << setprecision(30) << st * odds << '\n'` to get more idea of what is going on.

Comment: Thanks M.M!  I'll give it a try now

Comment: Classic educational material: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: M.M this is with setprecision() used:

without precision: 1179999999
with precision: 1180000000

Comment: Why don't you post the result you get? Maybe we can help you count zeros :)

Comment: I posted the results above Smac89 :)  Note, when I wrap the math in abs(), the proper result returns:

    int64_t res = abs(st * odds);

The above yields:

without precision: 1180000000
with precision: 1180000000

Comment: Also see previous [`1.18` question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187562/issue-with-floating-points-representation) and the pointers within.

Comment: @IInspectable - the expected result is 1180000000 and the actual result is: 1179999999

Comment: @IInspectable - edited, pardon.

Answer (score 7):

1.18, or *118 / 100* can't be exactly represented in binary, it will have repeating decimals. The same happens if you write *1 / 3* in decimal.

So let's go over a similar case in decimal, let's calculate *(1 / 3) × 30000*, which of course should be *10000*:

- *odds = 1 / 3* and *st = 30000*

  Since computers have only a limited precision we have to truncate this number to a limited number of decimals, let's say 6, so:
- *odds = 0.333333*
- *0.333333 × 10000 = 9999.99*. The cast *(which in your program is implicit)* will truncate this number to *9999*.

There is no 100% reliable way to work around this. `float` and `double` just have only limited precision. Dealing with this is a hard problem.

Your program contains an implicit cast from `double` to an integer on the line `int64_t res = st * odds;`. Many compilers will warn you about this. It can be the source of bugs of the type you are describing. This cast, which can be explicitly written as `(int64_t) some_double`, rounds the number towards zero.

An alternative is rounding to the nearest integer with `round(some_double);`. That will—in this case—give the expected result.

Comment: Your last para isn't correct.  The behaviour of `int64_t res = st * odds;` and `int64_t res = (int64_t)(st * odds);` is defined to be exactly the same - in both cases the expression `st * odds` is converted to `int64_t`, and the behaviour of this conversion is *implementation-defined* if the result of the multiplication is not exactly representible in `int64_t`.

Comment: "You should not implicitely cast double to an integer" is a matter of opinion - mine is that using a cast to hide a warning is not ideal either

Comment: @M.M yes, but sometimes you just need to round a double to an integer. I have the habit of always explicitly using a function like `floor` or `round`.

Comment: The `round` one is a good habit. There are some issues with `floor(x+0.5)` (it doesn't work for negative numbers, and it starts to behave strangely when you get to a certain magnitude of number)

Comment: @M.M Good point about large numbers. But for negative numbers `floor(-1.9999 + 0.5)` returns `-2.0` as expected, or doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll try with round() instead and post the results

Comment: I see → [Harder than it looks: rounding float to nearest integer, part 1](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1)

Answer (score 2):

First of all - `1.18` is not exactly representable in `double`. Mathematically the result of:

```
double odds = 1.18;
```

is `1.17999999999999993782751062099`  (according to an online calculator).

So, mathematically, `odds * st` is `1179999999.99999993782751062099`.

But in C++, `odds * st` is an expression with type `double`. So your compiler has two options for implementing this:

- Do the computation in `double` precision
- Do the computation in higher precision and then round the result to `double`

Apparently, doing the computation in `double` precision in IEEE754 results in exactly `1180000000`.

However, doing it in `long double` precision produces something more like `1179999999.99999993782751062099`

Converting this to `double` is now *implementation-defined* as to whether it selects the next-highest or next-lowest value, but I believe it is typical for the next-lowest to be selected.

Then converting this next-lowest result to integer will truncate the fractional part.

---

There is an [interesting blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/) here where the author describes the behaviour of GCC:

- It uses long double intermediate precision for x86 code (due to the x87 FPUs long double registers)
- It uses actual types for x64 code (because the SSE/SSE2 FPU supports this more naturally)

According to the C++11 standard you should be able to inspect which intermediate precision is being used by outputting `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` from `<cfloat>`. `0` would mean actual values, `2` would mean long double is being used.

Comment: I'm not sure my answer completely explains things; `double d = st * odds; int64_t res = d;` produces a different result to `int64_t res = (double)(st * odds);`  (where the cast is redundant but illustrative).  It seems like either (a) the compiler is going straight from intermediate result to `int64`, which I don't think the standard allows, or (b) the compiler is doing a compile-time optimization to compute `res1`, and using different precision than a runtime calculation of the same thing would give (again I'm not sure if the standard permits this)

Comment: round() seems to have done it and I've modified the value of 'odds' a few times to ensure it was consistent.  Thanks everyone for your input and help!